# First-Order Topology

Tags: general-topology, first-order-logic

Is it possible to formalise topology in first-order logic? When one associates a first-order structure to a topological space, what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topology is not first-order definable, since it is defined in terms of subsets. However, one can define a *topological first-order structure* as follows:

First recall that a *first-order language* $\cal L$ consists of a set $\cal R$ of
*relation symbols* and a set $\cal F$ of *function symbols*,
and associated to each element $r\in \cal R$ (resp.  $f\in \cal F$) a
positive (resp.  non-negative) integer called the *arity* of $r$
(resp. $f$).  For each integer $n$, we let $\cal R_n$ (resp.  $\cal F_n$) be
the set of relation (resp.  function) symbols of arity $n$.  The elements
of $\cal F_0$ are called *constants*.

An $\cal L$-structure $S$ is a *topological
$\cal L$-structure* if the set $S$ is equipped with a topology such that:

1. for each $f\in \cal F_n$ ($n > 0$), the mapping $(s_1,\ldots,
   s_n)\mapsto f(s_1,\ldots, s_n)$, from $S^n$ into $S$, is continuous, and
2. for each $r\in \cal R_n$ ($n > 0$), the subset $r$ of $S^n$ is
   closed.

Comment: Is a closure algebra, i.e., a boolean algebra equipped with a closure operator, a topological first-order structure? My goal is to show that the elementary theory of topology is undecidable by showing that the elementary theory of closure algebra is undecidable. I have so far been able to prove the latter.

Comment: This is a different question. I suggest that you ask a separate question.